# php how to return only character value from the variable

Tags: php

i am using following code to return only digital values from the variable, wounder how to get only character value "testing" from the variable and want to remove "on" from the string.

```
<?php
$valuecheck="testing on 123568";
$check1=preg_replace('/\D/', '', $valuecheck);
echo $check1;
?>

Output required:

testing
```

Thanks

Comment: so you want $check1 to be `testing 123568`?

Comment: Is that format going to be fixed, so you could just grab the first 7 characters of the string? Or are there going to be multiple variations, and you're always looking for the first word on the line no matter how long?

Comment: Marc B - no i want only "testing" as output

Comment: andrewsi - i don't want to do like this, i want to get rid of digital values first then wants to remove "on" from it.

Comment: Right. But is the input always going to be in the same format? Can you get away with removing the digits, and then trimming four characters off the end of what remains?

Comment: look i done it as Kolink stated.....

Comment: $check1=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $value2);  but here question is that how to remove "on" from the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `\D`, use `[^a-zA-Z]` (assuming that's what you mean by "character value"). Basically, put `[^SOMETHING]`, where that "something" is a set of all the characters you want to consider valid.

Comment: thanks kolink, how to remove "on" from the value. i want "testing" as output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid my solution would be a little more verbose:

```
$result = '';
$c = explode( ' ', $valuecheck );
foreach ($c as $ci) {
    if (preg_match( '[\D]', $ci ) == 1) { continue; }
    $result = $ci; break;
}
echo $result;
```

Treating space as a delimiter, this will ignore any strings with at least one numeric and return the first "qualified" string found.